# ThreadPool Callback error when integrating Blazor custom element in ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, blazor, blazor-webassembly, custom-element

I'm integrating Blazor components, compiled to custom elements, into a legacy ASP.NET MVC application. The development process involves initially developing the component in a standalone Blazor app (to take advantage of hot module reloading) and subsequently publishing it. Once published, I move the files over to the ASP.NET MVC application.

However, I've been encountering a puzzling error only when the compiled custom element is used in the ASP.NET MVC application. The error states:

> ThreadPool Callback threw an unhandled exception of type System.ObjectDisposedException

The strange part is, I do not face this error in the standalone Blazor app. It exclusively occurs in the ASP.NET MVC context.

Here's the relevant part of my service where the problem arises:

```cs
// ... [Namespace imports]

public class WirelessDevicesNewService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _HttpClient;

    public WirelessDevicesNewService(IHttpClientFactory _p_HttpClientFactory)
    {
        _HttpClient = _p_HttpClientFactory.CreateClient(nameof(WirelessDevicesNewService));
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<DeliveryCenterModel>> GetDeliveryCenters()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_HttpClient); // <- This line logs correctly
        var _dto = await _HttpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<DeliveryCenterDto>>("xApi/DeliveryCenters");
        Console.WriteLine(_dto);  // <- The exception is thrown before this line is reached
        //... [Remaining logic]
    }
   //...
}
```

I've confirmed through logging that the error doesn't appear to originate from within my custom handler. Furthermore, here's the relevant code from my `Program.cs`:

```cs
// ... [Namespace imports]

Syncfusion.Licensing.SyncfusionLicenseProvider.RegisterLicense("Mylicence");
var _builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
//... [Other configurations]

_builder.Services.AddTransient<WirelessDeviceNewFakeHttpMessageHandler>();
_builder.Services.AddHttpClient<WirelessDevicesNewService>(_p_Client =>
{
    _p_Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress);
})
    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler<WirelessDeviceNewFakeHttpMessageHandler>();

_builder.Services.AddScoped<WirelessDevicesNewService>();

_builder.RootComponents.RegisterCustomElement<WirelessDevicesNew>("x-wireless-devices");

//... [Other services registration]

await _builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

I'm currently at a loss as to what might be causing this discrepancy between the two contexts (Blazor app vs ASP.NET MVC with custom elements). Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.